# Extruding cylinder through a die

Tags: animation, extrude

I'm trying to reshape the cylinder into a hollow rectangular prism as it extrudes out of the cube box on the left side
What I tried was making everything a rigid body, except the cylinder, moving through the block and coming out the other side, a soft body. I am expecting the cylinder to squash through the die(box) and reshape into the opening shape.

The closest thing I found online was this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qukUEn-XB4&ab_channel=PIXXO3D.

This video uses a boolean. I wanted something more like a physics animation.
Or if someone knows how to apply the method in the video to my application.

[image]

[image: Start]
[image: End]
[image: Die]

Comment: Doing this with physics is a bad idea.  Do it with a boolean like shown.  **Blender physics are not real physics!**  This cannot be emphasized enough.  They are tools to make pictures, and asking "what would physics do" is backwards, Blender physics is for you to make it do what you want it to do.  Other than that, rigid bodies and soft bodies do not interact, they are separate simulations.  Use collision modifier/physics if you want to affect a soft body.

Comment: Although Nathan is 97% right ;) ....you can try and tweak the physics often in that way, that it..."kind of" works:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLdSx.gif. this was done with soft body simulation. Yes, it is not perfect. Yes, it goes through the box....but it "kind of" works and it think it is pretty impressive, what Blenders physic simulation can do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it by doing this:

select your

[image]

press Shift-D, return, then tab into edit mode,

select these front vertices, then press G Y and make it as big as this:

[image]

Then rename it to "Fake" and hide it in viewport and render like this:

[image]

Then select your ...004 and change the boolean object to your newly created fake object.

result:

[image]

[image]

> Note: another way is using the lattice modifier...